# Why was my flag for "Is Liberalism a Mental Disorder" ignored?

Tags: discussion

I flagged the following question for being Not Constructive and Not a Real Question

[Is the claim of liberalism being a psychological disorder accurate?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9099/is-liberalism-a-mental-disorder)

I even tried to edit the question to make it somewhat salvagable but I am convinced that in its current state that it is completely unanswerable.

My flag was marked 'Helpful' but no action was taken.

Reading the FAQ, I do not understand why such a low quality question and poor claim should remain open?

Comment: i agree with you. I have asked for the question to be removed, but no action has been taken.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to confuse you. I did acknowledge your flag, but I disagree that the question is to be closed.

I do not like the question, as a lot of other people (it sits at -8 atm, but was at -3 at the time of the flag, iirc), however it is about a claim and it is worded neutrally.

If on this site we allow questions denying basic science, such as moon-landing denial questions, then I do not think it would be appropriate to close the question on those basis.

That said, the question is answerable. Does Barack Obama qualify as a psychopath as claimed? Yes or no, job done.

The question did not receive any close votes or other flags from the downvoters.

I did not decline your flag because you have less than 3k rep and could not vote to close.

Comment: @Skliwz Thanks for the information!  I wasn't around during the early stages of beta where these things were figured out.  I will continue to be "skeptical" where I can get the reputation to vote to close.  Thank you.